# Multiple git config in a git alias alias

Tags: git, config

I would like to set a git alias to configure my `user.name` and `user.email` quickly.

I tried to play with the `--add`option but I wasn't able to do something like :

```
[alias]
  cfTest = config --add user.email "test@test.com" --add user.name "test"
```

All I got is :

```
error: wrong number of arguments
```

I would like to do it with git alias but if it's impossible i will do it with regular bash alias.

How would you do ?

Comment: The description for the `--add` flag reads as follows: *Adds a new line to the option without altering any existing values. This is the same as providing `^$` as the value_regex in `--replace-all`*. I don't think that's what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass the -add option multiple times to a single `git config` command, you will need to call `git config` twice.

```
[aliasl]
     cfgTest = !git config user.name "Andy" && git config user.email "Andrew@nowhere.com"
```

Comment: `[aliasl]`? Is that a typo?

Comment: Excellent, thanks =) How did you find this ? Reminds me of a vim `:!` bash command

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html - "If the alias expansion is prefixed with an exclamation point, it will be treated as a shell command"